# MultiBinding with StringFormat - Why is the targetType == object in the inner converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, type-conversion

I'm binding two strings using **Multibinding** and **StringFormat** to a TextBox. I've noticed something strange when I add a Converter to one of the inner bindings, like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}  {1} ">
            <Binding Path="Foo" 
                        Converter="{StaticResource someConverter}" 
                        ConverterParameter="true" />
            <Binding Path="Bar"  />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

In the converter the **TargetType** property is going to be **object**. Using the same converter directly on a Text property (without the multibinding) it is **string**.

I'm wondering *why* is that happening, and if there is any way of letting the converter know about the type of the *parent* binding (not sure if the terminology is correct here).

The reason I'm asking is that I'm usually checking the to/from types in the converters and I return Binding.DoNothing if there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the **someConverter** directly on a Text property, the **TargetType** will be **String**, because it's based on the Type of Text property. But when you use a converter in Binding which is placed inside MultiBinding, there is no information about TargetType and **Object** is used by default.

Maybe you are familiar with **IMultiValueConverter**, so when you use it, the **TargetType** will be **String** as you expected. Look at the example bellow:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}  {1} " Converter="{StaticResource someMultiConverter}" ConverterParameter="true" >
      <Binding Path="Foo" />
      <Binding Path="Bar"  />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's clear that the inner binding is not a direct child of the Text, but of the MultiBinding, but using the StringFormat I would have assumed it expects strings. Now what you're suggesting is an acceptable workaround (as is not being so fussy about the type validation in the converter) but it would require duplicating the existing converters (now with multivalue) for the same task.